# Angular 8 fails to directly go to lazy loaded modules after prod deploy

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Cannot browse directly to a lazy loaded module in production mode on IIS

I have downloaded lazy-loading-ngmodules.zip from

```
 https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules.
```

I ran the app using ng serve with no problem. I can browse url

```
http://localhost:4200
```

and click on Customers and Orders which both are lazy loaded modules. I also can directly browse the url -

```
http://localhost:4200/customers.
```

Then I built production version using ng build --prod and hosted it on IIS. I can browse the url http://localhost:80 and click on Customers and Orders to navigate to lazy loaded modules. No problems!!! However, if I browse directly to the url http://localhost:80/customers, I got HTTP 404 Error. Why??? I need to directly browse to the lazy loading modules.

Should be able to directly browse the lazy loaded module in production mode on IIS.

Comment: What is the url you got, when you click on customers, is it http://localhost:80/customers  ?

Comment: The page wasn't displayed at all. IIS showed 404 error page. I found out if I create a sub-folder called customers and copy all the published files to there too, then direct browse works.

Comment: Here is IIS 404 error:HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.